# Writing PDEs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm a completely new user to Matlab. I want to calculate PDEs like this one: [PDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnEGR.png) But I have no idea how to code it.
I have tried `g(x)=diff(x,y)^2/(diff(x)*diff(y));` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: please, state clearly what you are trying to accomplish, write the equations and what you want to solve. The picture shows the calculation of a mixed partial derivative, which is completely different than solving a partial differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

By using the symbolic toolbox and `diff()` function the partial derivatives can be simplified as follows. I'm not sure if you'd like to solve any specific values or plots but going based on the image posted here are some techniques that may help.

**Example Partial Derivatives of Function `f` Taken with Respect to X and Y:**

```
%Creating symbolic variables/representations%
syms x y

%Function dependent on variables x and y%
f = 2*y*sin(5*x);

%Taking the partial derivative with respect to x%
g = diff(f,x);
%Taking the partial derivative with respect to y%
g = diff(g,y)
```

**Example Equation:**

[image: Equations]

### Extension: Graphing

Plotting the original function and its derivative can be done by using the `fsurf()` function which plot symbolic functions.

[image: Plotting Symbolic Functions]

```
%Plotting the symbolic result of the partial derivatives%
subplot(1,2,1); fsurf(f);
title('Original Function');
xlabel('X-Axis'); ylabel('Y-Label');

subplot(1,2,2); fsurf(g);
title('Derivative of Function');
xlabel('X-Axis'); ylabel('Y-Label');
```

### Extension: Evaluating at Specific Values

```
%Evaluating partial derivative at specific values%
x = 1;
y = 1;
Answer = subs(g);
Answer_As_A_Double = double(Answer);
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**